# How to set a max length for label text in Xamarin

Tags: xamarin.android

In xamarin, I would like a Label Text with a max length. When the text is too long, it is on several lines. So, I would like set a maximum length or number of lines. I think to measure the string length but I no found method.

I hope there is a solution to Xamarin. I don't want to do specific code for each platform if it's possible.

Thank you

Comment: You want this approach in xamarin.forms or xamarin.android ?

Answer (score 5):

`MaxLines` property is your answer. It's bindable too.

And if you want two show three dots after certain lines for overflowing text , use `LineBreakMode="TailTruncation"`

Example:

```
<Label Text="{Binding LargeText}"  MaxLines="2" LineBreakMode="TailTruncation"/>
```

Answer (score 2):

Have you looked at LineBreakMode? https://developer.xamarin.com/api/type/Xamarin.Forms.LineBreakMode/ 
This is what I used to actually make my labels longer.

Answer (score 1):

In Xamarin.Forms 3.4 you can use Label's "MaxLines" property to set maximum lines. Also, it's a bindable property